# Why do I need @Transactional for saving an OneToOne mapped Entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple straight forward demo application with spring-boot, spring-data-jpa and a h2-DB.

I have build two entities which are mapped by an `OneToOne` relationship.

Post.java

```
@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private PostDetail postDetail;
}
```

PostDetail.java

```
@Entity
public class PostDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String message;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Post post;
}
```

I try to create and save a new `Post`. Then I try to create a new `PostDetail`, set the previous generated `Post` to it and save it. In the one controller sample I dont have a `@Transactional` annotation and in the seconde sample I do annotate the method with `@Transactional`

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    
    @Autowired
    PostRepository postRepository;

    @Autowired
    PostDetailRepository postDetailRepository;

    @GetMapping("/test1")
    public String test1() {
        Post post = new Post();
        post.setId(2L);
        post.setTitle("Post 1");
        postRepository.save(post);
        
        PostDetail detail = new PostDetail();
        detail.setMessage("Detail 1");
        detail.setPost(post);
        
        postDetailRepository.save(detail);
        
        return "";
    }
    
    @Transactional
    @GetMapping("/test2")
    public String test2() {
        Post post = new Post();
        post.setId(2L);
        post.setTitle("Post 1");
        postRepository.save(post);
        
        PostDetail detail = new PostDetail();
        detail.setMessage("Detail 1");
        detail.setPost(post);
        
        postDetailRepository.save(detail);
        
        return "";
    }
}
```

Why do I get in the first sample a `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.demo.jpa.model.Post` exception and in the other sample not?

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use *bidirectional* `@OneToOne` association. As hibernate documentation [states](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional):

> Whenever a bidirectional association is formed, the application developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times.

So, you should rewrite your test method in this way:

```java
@GetMapping("/test1")
public String test1() {
   Post post = new Post();
   post.setId(2L);
   post.setTitle("Post 1");
   
   PostDetail detail = new PostDetail();
   detail.setMessage("Detail 1");
   
   // synchronization of both sides of @OneToOne association
   detail.setPost(post);
   post.setDetail(detail);
   

   // thanks to CascadeType.ALL on Post.postDetail
   // postDetail will be saved too
   postRepository.save(post);

   return "";
}
```

Comment: I followed [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) example and there its possible to have Post separetely saved. Any solution for that?

Comment: This article suggest you do not use bidirectional `@OneToOne`: `This way, you don’t even need a bidirectional association since you can always fetch the PostDetails entity by using the Post entity identifier.` You will not faced with this problem if you use unidirectional `@OneToOne`

Comment: And by the way, [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional-lazy) suggests it too: `Because this can lead to N+1 query issues, it’s much more efficient to use unidirectional @OneToOne associations with the @MapsId annotation in place.`

Comment: Ok understand that. But in docs there is also [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived) mentioned. Any suggestion to that?

Comment: I am confused, what exactly suggestion do you need?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t be saving those 2 entities separately — you should set PostDetail inside of post object and save only the Post object. Hibernate will take care of saving the aggregated PostDetail.

That is why you are getting `PersistentObjectException` which you are able to workaround by keeping it inside of the same transaction.

Comment: Any solution if I want to save it separetely?

Comment: you would need to create HibernateSessions manually each time before and close them manually, I wouldn't recommend it but you can use SessionFactory for that https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring

Answer (score 1):

```
we do not always need a bidirectional mapping when we are mapping two entities

you can simple have a unidirection most of the time

      Post post = new Post();
        post.setId(2L);
        post.setTitle("Post 1");
       
        PostDetail detail = new PostDetail();
        detail.setMessage("Detail 1");
        detail.setPost(post);
        postRepository.save(post);
```

as you have cascade.all ,so hibernate saves Post first and then it saves PostDetail, now as per the rule of Transaction behavior ,either it is completely done or not done,Hence we can not have the situation that Post is saved but PostDetail did not,Hence to avoid such ambiguity it is important to have @Transaction annotation ,at method level or may be class level as per your requirement